# Conky buffer too small?

Tags: conky

e.g.: my sample conkyrc (the last line is the only important part!):

```
background yes
use_xft yes
xftfont Terminus:size=8
xftalpha 0.8
update_interval 5.0
total_run_times 0
double_buffer yes
own_window yes
own_window_type override
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
minimum_size 0 0
draw_shades yes
draw_outline no
draw_borders no
stippled_borders 8
border_margin 0
border_width 0
default_color ffffff
default_shade_color black
default_outline_color ffffff
alignment top_left
# gap_x - 1280x800 = 1105; 1024x768 = 820
gap_x 1200
gap_y 0
no_buffers yes
uppercase no
cpu_avg_samples 2
net_avg_samples 2
override_utf8_locale yes
use_spacer yes
TEXT

${execpi 15 sleep $[ ($RANDOM % 3 ) ]; sh conkyscripts.sh}
```

AND

```
cat conkyscripts.sh 
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..40}; do echo "Welcome $i times"; done
```

So this should give output as the same as when doing "sh conkyscript.sh"

```
Welcome 1 times
Welcome 2 times
Welcome 3 times
Welcome 4 times
Welcome 5 times
Welcome 6 times
Welcome 7 times
Welcome 8 times
Welcome 9 times
Welcome 10 times
Welcome 11 times
Welcome 12 times
Welcome 13 times
Welcome 14 times
Welcome 15 times
Welcome 16 times
Welcome 17 times
Welcome 18 times
Welcome 19 times
Welcome 20 times
Welcome 21 times
Welcome 22 times
Welcome 23 times
Welcome 24 times
Welcome 25 times
Welcome 26 times
Welcome 27 times
Welcome 28 times
Welcome 29 times
Welcome 30 times
Welcome 31 times
Welcome 32 times
Welcome 33 times
Welcome 34 times
Welcome 35 times
Welcome 36 times
Welcome 37 times
Welcome 38 times
Welcome 39 times
Welcome 40 times
```

But nooooOO, because the conky gives this output to the Desktop:

[image]

Why? Why does it stop at 16? Is some buffer to small? Or conky can't write scripts output longer the 16 Lines or what? :O

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Counting the characters, conky is displaying 257 characters, which looks suspiciously like an arbitrary limit for a single line of TEXT in conky.  Add in some hidden quotes internally to conky, and the shell expansion, and you loose the "times" characters.  Conky used to limit what it displayed to the first 128 characters - they may have doubled this.

(15(+1 newline)=16 characters per line x 16 lines = 256 characters.

Found this googling:

http://lifehacker.com/5067341/customize-conky-for-ambient-linux-productivity

`If your to-do file or any other section is getting cut off too soon, that's because Conky has an unseen default text limit for any object. You can tweak it by adding a text_buffer_size 512 to the top section of your .conkyrc, changing that number to fit your needs.`

If your TEXT is long enough, you may need to either raise this limit even further, or break your script up into several commands.

Comment: we have a winner :)

Comment: @Lance, if you have a winner please actually award that bounty! If you don't do it manually, half of it goes to waste and since that has happened with your bounties in the past, it's not very good incentive for people to work hard on any of your future questions!

Comment: @Lance, thanks for coming back to actually award that.

Comment: ? i accepted the question days ago.. you wrote this 16 hours ago, am i missing st?:O:O